# what happens when i create instance by using new operator in java of a bean defined in spring configuration

Tags: spring, javabeans

As spring default scope is single ton. if i created object of that single ton bean in java using new operator, will it create a new object or what it will do.

Answer (score 2):

It will create a new object, but it won't be in Spring context, and thus will act like a simple Java class. To quote the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

> A bean is an object that is instantiated, assembled, and otherwise managed by a Spring IoC container. Otherwise, a bean is simply one of many objects in your application.